# Send Mail when symfony throw an error

Tags: php, email, symfony-1.4

Someone know if there is a way to send an email when symfony 1.4 throw an error with the details for the error?

Any comment will be use full to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [sfErrorNotifierPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfErrorNotifierPlugin). Not perfect, but it does it's job.